# Can we program our smartphone camera to detect the frequency and time period of IR light?

Tags: pcb, infrared, camera, light-sensor

My use case is this: I am emitting morse code using a sole IR light source, and I intend to detect the frequency and the time period of the light source using my smartphone camera. Can this be done?

Comment: Have you seen Null By Morse: Historical Optical Communication to
Smartphones? https://digitalartarchive.siggraph.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Schofield_paper.pdf

Comment: There is a "Morse Encoder & Decoder" app for android. I don't think it works well out of the box, but with a few tweaks in settings, it's not too bad. Proof of concept at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the smartphone camera actually sees IR. Most seem to these days.

More here: https://petapixel.com/2019/08/22/how-i-shoot-infrared-photography-with-a-smartphone/

This article shows the Samsung S10E, which apparently works. I looked into whether iPhones can see IR; it seems only the front camera can, but not the back, due to the back camera having an IR filter as part of its optics.

At any rate, you can test this on your own phone with just an IR TV remote and smartphone video: if the camera can see IR you will see flashing when the remote is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

To add more detail to Haktastical answer:

It depends on the smartphone.

Here it gets a bit trickier. Cameras do sense IR to a wavelength of about 1'000nm. However, to improve picture quality, most of the time a filter will be added in front of the lens to block the IR, except for some very cheap cameras.

The cutting wavelength may differ from one manufacturer to another. It is sometimes possible to mechanically remove the filter.

So it really depends if you want to have YOUR smartphone able to detect IR or if you want to distribute some app.

The best bet would be to select an IR source that is close to what the eye can perceive, so you have a good chance to be below the IR cutoff filter, without being too visible to the human eye, which would be around 750nm.

The second issue is the frequency. Our days' camera will have a capture rate of usually 60fps minimum. So your blinking frequency would need to be optimized considering aliasing.

For instance, your blinking rate would be the same as the camera capture rate, it may appear always on or always off, same goes for any subdivisions 1/2, 1/4 1/8, .... of that rate, so you need some "uneven" frequencies, much lower than the camera, like 12.8 Hz and some clever software to precisely define the rate such as counting the "blinks" and averaging over a period of time.